# Is it possible to ban a list of words with ESlint or anything else when pre-commit?

Tags: javascript, git, eslint, husky

I am using husky to deal with the pre-commit thing.

So here I want that the newly written program should not contain a list of words, like `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, etc.

I know there is a rule `no-danger` in eslint-plugin-react, but it only prevents that one word. How can I write a list of words in a file and use it as a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally solved this problem myself.

The solution lies in taking advantage of `git hook` and the `precommit`, which is one of those.

A good resource of achieving this is here:

[Pre-commit Git Hook that Prevents Commits with Undesired Words](https://medium.com/@edgar/pre-commit-git-hook-that-prevents-commits-with-undesired-words-usually-debugging-statements-b02bea43e0a2)

And with Husky, which is *"Git Hooks Made Easy"*, we first write a script, which is exactly like what has been showed in the blog above. Then we can add the hook itself in the `script` of `package.json`, which is like this:

```
"script": {
  "precommit": "./pre-commit.sh"
}
```

This means everytime you commit, the `pre-commit` script will be run first. And thus you can filter the words that are undesired.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, You should be able to write a new Eslint rule that takes in an array of prohibited words then run Eslint in a pre-commit script. I've done this using a git pre-commit script (not sure about husky, sorry).
For a starting point I would look at eslint-plugin-jasmine. The no focused test rule sets a list of prohibited words (ddescribe, iit, fdescribe, and fit) and checks code for these words. You could do the same thing but change the prohibited array to contain the words you want to ban.