# ESLint Rule to Exclude Certain Keywords and Phrases in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, tslint

I need to write an Angular Typescript rule to warn people if they utilize certain 'keywords/phrases'.
For example, if keyword "Birthdate" or "SSN" is in the source file directly, it should give a warning.

How would someone write this rule to restrict words using ESLint?

Trying to research currently, did not see any articles in Stackoverflow article search archive,

Curious how to manipulate example code below or (open to any other solutions),

I applied the following below "id-blacklist": ["SSN","Birthdate"], receiving error

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-blacklist

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "id-blacklist": ["SSN","Birthdate"]
    }
};
```

**Error:**

> Configuration for rule "id-blacklist" is invalid:Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error

**Other Resources:**

https://rangle.io/blog/custom-tslint-for-angular/

https://medium.com/@andrey.igorevich.borisov/writing-custom-tslint-rules-from-scratch-62e7f0237124

Comment: Hmm... don't you think a git pre-commit hook might be a better alternative? And isn't TSLint deprecated?

Comment: hi @JaredSmith we already have existing examples of this in our code, want to flag as warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it with pipeline check but you can with pre-commit as shown here:
[Is it possible to ban a list of words with ESlint or anything else when pre-commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643324/is-it-possible-to-ban-a-list-of-words-with-eslint-or-anything-else-when-pre-comm)

and you can do it with ESlint [TSlint is deprecated] like this:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-blacklist

Comment: hi, not try to prevent in precommit, I want it allowed, just with warnings

Comment: looking for coding example, this helps

Comment: So you can check the second solution if it helps you please upvote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
'no-restricted-syntax': [
      'error',
      'Literal[value=/^(special|zzz|xxx)$/i]',
      'BinaryExpression[right.value = /^(special|zzz|xxx)$/i]',
    ],
```

This rule is work for me, my requirement is we don't want some key will be hard code in repo.

It will show error if your code like below:

```js
const t = {
    pp: 'special',
};

const tt = 'special',

const f = (arg) => {
  return arg === 'special';
}

function ff(arg) {
  return arg === 'special';
}
```