# Is there an eslint rule to forbid a specific string of text?

Tags: eslint

Is there a rule in ESLint that would let you prohibit, for instance, any string from containing "foo"?

Comment: Check https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Comment: I suggest that you ask how to do it instead of asking if it exists or not. One could just answer with “yes”, which wouldn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to ban a list of words with ESlint or anything else when pre-commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643324/is-it-possible-to-ban-a-list-of-words-with-eslint-or-anything-else-when-pre-comm)

Comment: @Samathingamajig that would make a good answer to this question.

Comment: @A.L if you're talking about the duplicate comment, that's the point of a duplicate

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes, your answer says no but the duplicate shows a solution, I think you can put the solution in your answer.

Comment: @A.L the answers in that question say no, that you have to bodge your way into finding an external solution or make your own eslint rule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285475/113705), it looks like I can do it with the `no-restricted-syntax` rule

```
'no-restricted-syntax': [
  'error',
  'Literal[value=/^foo$/i]',
],
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `no-restricted-syntax` rule like this:

```json
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "error",
  "Literal[value=/\\bfoo\\b/i]"
]
```

And since you can use a Regular Expression here, you can do a whole lot, such as:

- No instance of "foo" anywhere, even as a substring: `/foo/i` (`i` = ignore upper/lowercase)
- No instance of a string with just "foo": `/^foo$/i`
- No instance of foo as its own word: `/\\bfoo\\b/i` (note the double `\\` since this is inside a string)