# Is there an ESLint rule to report always true or always false expressions?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

For testing purposes, I sometimes add `|| true` to make a boolean expression `true` of `&& false` to make it `false`.

Is there an ESLint or Typescript ESLint rule to report these hacks and make sure they don't get committed or at least not built/deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72647597/1654241), I came up with this config using [ESLint no-restricted-syntax rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax):

```js
{
  'no-restricted-syntax': [
    'error',
    {
      selector: 'LogicalExpression[operator="||"][right.value=true]',
      message: '|| true is only for testing',
    },
    {
      selector: 'LogicalExpression[operator="&&"][right.value=false]',
      message: '&& false is only for testing',
    },
  ]
}
```